# Android authentication and services API

Tags: android, authentication

In my android application I am trying to build an array of login credential methods for the user. The user should be able to login using their google, facebook, outlook and twitter (etc...) credentials. I am not sure if there is an easy way to do this but currently I am looking up the API for each one of the mentioned services and researching how to use their authentication method and gaining access to services like contacts for invitation purposes.

I am having a hard time finding any resources for outlook authentication and services. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Socialauth-Android](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/):

> The API enables user authentication and sharing updates through different various social networks and hides all the intricacies of generating signatures & token, doing security handshakes and provide an easy mechanism to build cool social apps.